# Reference on matrix differentiation?

Tags: calculus, matrices, reference-request

Is there any good resource on matrix differentiation? I am seeing lots of questions like

> ...Consider $L(\vec{x},\lambda)=f(\vec{x})-\lambda^T (A\vec{x} - \vec{b}).$ Let's take derivative with respect to $\vec{x}$ and $\lambda$...

I found some notes online but the funny thing was different notes seem to use different notations and definitions thus I was utterly confused...

Comment: Did you check the external links section on the [Wikipedia page on Matrix Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus)? *The Matrix Cookbook* looks particularly useful.

Comment: You can have a look on [Matrix Differential Calculus with Applications to in Statistics and Econometrics](http://www.janmagnus.nl/misc/mdc2007-3rdedition) by Magnus and Neudecker. It's very good and freely available on the author's webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Matrix Cookbook is the most comprehensive one. Can't post the link due to my missing rep., but it's first hit on Google.

See these, too:
[Matrix Calculus - Colorado](http://www.colorado.edu/engineering/CAS/courses.d/IFEM.d/IFEM.AppF.d/IFEM.AppF.pdf) and [Matrix Algebra - LMU - German](http://www.statistik.lmu.de/~kneib/regressionsbuch/download/matrixanhang.pdf).